# How to login to a website using PHP curl commands

Tags: php, curl, cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I'm trying to login to this site using PHP curl commands:

https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/

So far my code looks like this

`

```
  $ch = curl_init(); 

  curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://users.premierleague.com/accounts/login/',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36',
    CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
      'login' => 'username',
      'password' => 'password',
      'app' => 'plfpl-web',
      'redirect_uri' => 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/a/login'
    ),
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => $cookie_file_path,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => $cookie_file_path
  ));

  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

`

When I run this in a browser though it doesn't login. I get a new cookie file in `$cookie_file_path` but no successful login. It just takes prints out the login page html. I've tried analysing things using the networks tab in chrome developer tools, but am none the wiser. I'm guessing it has something to do with a session cookie. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: This site uses CSRF tokens to prevent you from doing exactly this.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Ah ok, I didn't realise that's what CSRF tokens did. I've just wasted hours trying to do this :(

Comment: Well that's not technically their intended purpose, but that's a nice side effect. You might be able to request the page, parse out the token, then submit it back along with your login attempt.

Comment: I'm surprised there isn't a workaround of some sort. I mean, if I can login using the browser there must be a way I can login on the command line surely?

Comment: Many sites (like ones that contain sports scores) don't want their content to be scraped by automated processes, and so intentionally make their login process really difficult to script.

Comment: If they offer an API, you'd be much better off with that.

Comment: You didn't *waste* any hours you just learned a bunch of cool stuff :D

Comment: @AlexHowansky it was actually their API I was trying to access downstream. Some of the pages are behind an authorisation wall too though.

Comment: @IsThisJavascript haha well I suppose so. And I've made a mental note to go away and learn more about CSRF tokens.